# Problema con array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un problema utilizando array.
Estoy intentando sumar la nota media de `'persona1'+'persona2'` y dividir el resultado entre el número de personas para que me imprima la media de notas entre estas dos personas. Pero, el resultado no es el que espero ya que me muestra la media de `'persona1'` y despues la media entre `'persona1'+'persona2'`.

```
$persona1 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre1',
   'edad' => 25,
   'notas' => [1,2,3,4]
];

$persona2 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre2',
   'edad' => 21,
   'notas' => [5,6,7,8]
];

$persona3 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre3',
   'edad' => 32,
   'notas' => [5,1,3,4]
];

$datos=[$persona1, $persona2, $persona3];


$suma = 0;

foreach($datos as $persona){

    if($persona['edad'] < 29){

        $media = array_sum($persona['notas'])/count($persona['notas']);

        $suma = $suma + $media;

        echo $suma . " ";

    }
}

// El resultado que me muestra es : 2.5 9 
// El resultado que necesito es : 9
// No entiendo por que me muestra ese 2.5, el 2.5 entiendo que es la suma de las notas de persona1 divida entre el numero de notas.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu logica es correcta, al final la variable guarda el valor de 9 que es lo que necesitas pero la estas imprimiendo en la primera iteracion por lo que te muestra

> 2.5 9

que es el resultado en cada iteracion, solo imprime la variable `$suma` fuera del foreach y te mostrara el resultado correcto:

```
$persona1 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre1',
   'edad' => 25,
   'notas' => [1,2,3,4]
];

$persona2 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre2',
   'edad' => 21,
   'notas' => [5,6,7,8]
];

$persona3 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre3',
   'edad' => 32,
   'notas' => [5,1,3,4]
];

$datos=[$persona1, $persona2, $persona3];


$suma = 0;

foreach($datos as $persona){

    if($persona['edad'] < 29){

        $media = array_sum($persona['notas'])/count($persona['notas']);

        $suma = $suma + $media;

        //echo $suma . " ";

    }
}
//Imprimes luego de que realizas todas las iteraciones
echo($suma);//Imprime 9
```